# Can someone explain the parsing of this code? The relation between double.parseDouble and JOptionPane?

Tags: java, parsing

I've been given this chunk of code to understand, but having issues with the "parsing-part".

tried googling but having a hard time gripping this.

```
import javax.swing.*;

    public class FahrenheitCelsius {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            double f;

            f = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write the 
                        temperature in fahrenheit:"));
            do {
                if (f > 0 && f < 18032) {

                    double c = ((f - 32) * 5) / 9;

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The 
                                    temperature is " + c + "°C");
                    break;

                } else {
            f = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
    ("Not a valid value, try again"));
                }
            } while (f > 18032 || f < 1);
        }

    }
```

It works well and fine, just trying to understand how it works, im not that great in programming! :)

Comment: JOptionPane.showInputDialog() will get an input from user and after that it would parse as double and go on.

Comment: The javadocs are lacking a bit - the docs for the form of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(String)` you are using doesn't specify the @return value (it's what is entered in the dialog) - but the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` with 7 parameters does state it and it can be assumed for the other forms.  this is the doc link for the 7-param version: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: Also slight logic error due to duplicate code - if one enters 18032 it will indicate "Not a valid value..." and then exit (the while) - which is probably not what is intended.